# Calculation of calendar days

Tags: education

Is the day a child is born counted when calculating the calender days for his birthday? For instance,
Kadogo was born on 4th January 2009.How old was he on 4th March 2011?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In $4$th January, $2011$, he'll be $2$ years old. After $59$ days, i.e., in $4$th March, he'll be $2$ years $59$ days.

Comment: kindly explain why not 2years 60 days

Comment: Because at 11:59 PM of 4th January, he's completing his 2nd year. That's why I'm not counting it. Now see, it depends on how you take the time of his birth, so it can be varied from one to two days.